# Testing Facebook Payments without a company

Tags: facebook, facebook-credits

I want to integrate [Facebook Payments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/) into my app. I'm developing using a development Facebook app which is separate from the live app. However, to enable Facebook payments on this app it appears I must first enter company details, which I don't have yet.

Is there a way around that? Again, just for development and testing, not for real payments.

Note: I have another, older, development app, for a different application altogether, which has the 'Company Country' set, and it appears I can test payments for that app. However, the country option is not visible in my new app.

Comment: Update: I've done it the "right way" now and had the company registered, but am still interested in an answer for the future.

Comment: I don't think it's possible anymore. They updated it recently.